# Reading and writing on net.Conn

Tags: sockets, encoding, io, go

I am trying to read and write data from a net.Conn but since I have only Read([]byte) and Write([]byte) functions, I am finding quite hard to find helper functions to do this job.

I need to read and write the following types:

- uint64
- byte
- uint32
- UTF-8 encoded string ( first a uint32 length and the string data after)

**In Short**

Is there anything like Java's DataInputStream and DataOutputStream in Go's packages ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: To/from another Go process? Then take a look to the package encoding/gob: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/

Comment: No. It is suposed to be a platform agnostic protocol

Comment: Then you may want to take a look to encoding/binary. But pure binary format is not so good for a platform-agnostic transmission, there are issues associated to the big/little endian, data size, etc.

Comment: encoding/binary can transform uint64 and uint32 to []byte. byte and string are easily transformed (http://play.golang.org/p/f0L5-083ql)

Comment: I was able to read basic data types using binary package. The deal now is to read strings. I wonder GO have something lika java's DataInputStream/DataOutputStream

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide on a format to marshal to and from. Your choices are to either roll your own format or to use one that was already made. I highly recommend the latter.

I have previously posted about many of the formats supported in the go standard library here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575325/727643

If you decide to roll your own, then uints can be encoded and decoded from []byte using `encoding/binary`. It gives you the option of both little and big endian. Strings can be converted directly to []byte using `[]byte(str)`. Finally, bytes can just be sent as bytes. No magic needed.

I will stress that making up your own format is normally a bad idea. I tend to use JSON by default and use others only when I can get a significant performance increase and I believe it worth the time to do it.

Comment: Does converting a string to bytes using []byte(string) converts to UTF8 encoded characters ?

Comment: A string is very much like an immutable byte slice. It is defined as containing a utf8 string. Most Go libraries including all of the standard libs assume this. However, this is not enforced and a string COULD be any string of bytes. You can ensure your strings are utf8 using http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#ValidString.

Comment: Note that if you have a literal like "xyz", it will be utf8.

Comment: Regarding strings: now I am curently having problems in reading an UTF8 encoded byte stream writen from java.
As I said, I send the string length as a uint32 and create a byte slice with this length, read the stream and cast it to string.

Comment: Number of bytes and number of characters are not the same for UTF8. Also check that the number looks OK and not very big due to wrong endian.

Comment: I ser . As per what I read, a Go Rune is 32 bit long and UTF8 chars are 1 to 4 byte long. Thats why casting the bytes to string does no work. I have the string length in bytes, but still I haven't found a way to read this bytes.

Answer (score 1):

One little secret of binary encoding is that you can write and read entire data structures:

From the [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/11yW3MEWMH)

```
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &MyMessage{
    First:   100,
    Second:  0,
    Third:   100,
    Message: MyString{0, [10]byte{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\n'}},
    })

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("binary.Read failed:", err)
    return
}

// <<--- CONN -->>
msg := new(MyMessage)

err2 := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, msg)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Printf("binary.Read failed:", err2)
    return
}
```

Pay attention at the kind of types that you can use:

from [binary/encoding](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) docs:

> A fixed-size value is either a fixed-size arithmetic type (int8, uint8, int16, float32, complex64, ...) or an array or struct containing only fixed-size values.

notice then that you have to use `[10] byte` and can't use `[]byte`

Answer (score 0):

Fabrizio's answer is good and I would like to add that you should probably wrap your socket with a buffered reader and buffered writer from the bufio package:

http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/