# How to write a user defined struct object in net.Conn.Write()

Tags: go, tcpserver

I have a simple TCP server listening on a port. How to write an object of type user defined in `net.Conn.Write()`?

My code is given below:

```
func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    msgchan := make(chan string)
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize the object into a `[]byte` or `io.Reader`

Some solutions in the standard library include [gob](https://godoc.org/encoding/gob) and [json](https://godoc.org/encoding/json).

Comment: Thanks,
I used json to convert into []byte using Marshal() function,and then write into net.Conn.Write(). But on the receiving end I am unable to convert it into original form.

Comment: @Raja Hammad Farooq make sure your objects' fields are exported. Only your package can access internal fields.

Comment: Since these question turns up in Google Search, here is the link to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165768/reading-and-writing-on-net-conn).