# Password hash does not match hash attempt despite the password matching the attempt

Tags: json, go, struct, hash, sha1

I have a "createUser" function on a Go server in which I hash a new user's password and store their data from a form sent via POST.

The database of users and their stats is pulled up and converted into a string map containing structs with their info. It looks like this:

```
var userStruct struct {
  Users map[string]struct {
    Admin, Moderator, Root bool
    Pass                   *string
  }
}
```

The reason it is a pointer is because later on I might want to change the password.

So, when I create a new user I unmarshal the JSON from the POST request into a struct like this:

```
var newUser struct{
  Username, Password string
  IsAdmin, IsModerator bool
}
```

I use `json.NewDecoder` to decode it into the struct as follows:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&newUser)
```

Then, I hash it and store the results using `sha`, `json.MarshalIndent` and `ioutil.WriteFile`:

```
sha := sha1.New()
sha.Write([]byte(newUser.Password))
var hashedPass string;
hashedPass = hex.EncodeToString(sha.Sum(nil))
fmt.Println(hashedPass)
userStruct.Users[newUser.Username] = struct {
    Admin, Moderator, Root bool
    Pass                   *string
}{
    Admin:     newUser.IsAdmin,
    Moderator: newUser.IsModerator,
    Root:      false,
    Pass:      &hashedPass,
}
fmt.Println(*userStruct.Users[newUser.Username].Pass)
    file, _ := json.MarshalIndent(userStruct, "", " ")
_ = ioutil.WriteFile("userInfo.json", file, 0644)
```

Then, on the login side, I convert the string slice of the parsed form of the credentials to a byte slice and compare the username/password to the ones stored in the database.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575325/14409978), which shows that I can use the Gob encoder:

```
r.ParseForm()
sha := sha1.New()
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(r.Form["password"])
bufBytes := buf.Bytes()
sha.Write(bufBytes)
bs := sha.Sum(nil)
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(bs))
usrJSON, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("userInfo.json")
var userStruct struct {
    Users map[string]struct {
        Root, Admin, Moderator bool
        Pass                   *string
    }
}
json.Unmarshal(usrJSON, &userStruct)
username := strings.ToLower(strings.Join(r.Form["username"], "")
```

I then compare the username and the password. The password comparing is the only problem we need to focus on, though:

```
if *userStruct.Users[username].Pass == hex.EncodeToString(bs) {
}
```

Attempting to debug, I outputted the results of the hashing in both the user creation function, *and* the user login function.

The password I used for an example is `myverysecretpassword`.

The stored hash looks like this:

`7816b9b6485dd785aab9f91a31a0b80997ed44b9`

The password attempt looks like this:

`08618c3225370a2205d698d06df48ba4b820c1d4`

As I look deeper and deeper into this, I realize that it might be my usage of pointers/addresses, but I'm still confused anyways.

What is going on?

Comment: Why are you getting `gob` involved when validating the password? That's almost certainly what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Adrian I was wondering if that was the case. I needed to convert the string slice into a byte slice because `httpRequest.Form` returns a string slice. Also, this works fine with another user that I copy-pasted the password hash directly into the database, so I think it might be something with my use of pointers/references/addresses.

Comment: It's nothing to do with pointers/references/addresses, it's your use of `gob` here. You want to get rid of it and just `sha.Write([]byte(r.Form.Get("password"))` instead.

Comment: @Adrian Oh wow, what do you know it worked!

Why though? Why is `gob` causing this?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but a simple sha1 hash is **not at all secure**. It is vulnerable to a number of different attacks; sha1 has been compromised, you're not salting values, and a single iteration of SHA is not sufficiently computationally expensive. If you're storing passwords, [HMAC](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/hmac) is preferable, but if you need something easier to use, look to [bcrypt](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt).

Comment: `gob` is an encoder. It's encoding the value you give it. The encoded value and the raw value are not equal, so their hashes are not equal.

Comment: @Adrian the program is not necessarily going to be popular (at least not now), but it is always a good idea to add as much security as you can, so I'll have a "go" (haha) at that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I didn't quite understand this at the bottom of the answer on the post about converting string slices to byte slices:

> Gob is simple and to the point. However, the format is only readable with other Go code.

Reading it a couple of times makes sense, Go encoding isn't meant to convert a string slice directly to a byte slice.

According to the comments, Gob is an encoder, not a string slice to byte slice converter.

I can use `http.Request.Form.Get("key")` instead, to get the data as a string and convert it into bytes using `[]byte()`.